# Total Import Pro Prestashop Error

Tags: php, import, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Hi I use total import pro and it cant import csv file. There is an error - no idea if there is a problem on MODULE, PRESTASHOP or WEBHOSTING

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /data/web/virtuals/130258/virtual/www/domains/napilu.cz/modules/totalimportpro/totalimportpro.php
>   on line 2107
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /data/web/virtuals/130258/virtual/www/domains/napilu.cz/modules/totalimportpro/totalimportpro.php:2107)
>   in
>   /data/web/virtuals/130258/virtual/www/domains/napilu.cz/classes/Tools.php
>   on line 252

Comment: I'll suggest to ask to module developers (if you bought it)

Comment: We really can't help you there as maybe none of us has bought/installed that specific module.

Answer (score 0):

All what we can see is that the code as a 2107 line error, which have the effect of planting the page. But without seeing the code in question it's going to be complicated to help.

Regards,